# Horizontal navigation bar messes up when I resize window plus more

Tags: html, css

I am working on making a website that sells music as a class project. I made a horizontal navigation bar but when I resize the window... it messes up. 
PICS:
Full screen on my laptop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIqpE.png
Resized:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/KTtymX5.png]

Heres my code for the bar:
The css part

```
 span{}
.bar{
display:inline;
padding:2.5cm;
}

#top{
background-color:#000000;
padding:16px;
}

#top a{
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
}

#top a:hover{
background-color:#FF9900;
}
```

Heres the html part:

```
<span id="top">
<li class="bar"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="bar"><a href="">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
                        <li class="bar"><a href="">POPULAR</a></li>
                        <li class="bar"><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li class="bar"><a href="">CONNECT</a></li>
    </span>
```

how do I fix this?

Question 2) how do I make an image appear beside my vertical navigation bar? When i do float:right for the image, it goes to the right but it does so below the navigation bar not beside it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you have to write `media-query` for different screen size and menu appearance.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1** try to use

```
.bar{
   display:inline-block;
   padding:2.5em;
 }
```

**Q2** to append an image u can use `background-image:` or pseudo element `:before`

Answer (score 0):

```
 .bar{
       display:inline-block;
       padding:5px;
      width:19.233333%;
      border:1px solid red;
      float:left;
      position:relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used li tag under span which is incorrect. li should always be within ul tag. Best way to create menu is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul.header{
    background-color:#000000;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:16px;
}
ul.header li{
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
ul.header li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
ul.header li a:hover{
    background-color:#FF9900;
}
ul.vertical-nav {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    list-style:none;
}
ul.vertical-nav li {
    padding:5px 10px;
}
ul.vertical-nav li img {
    margin:0 5px;
    border:1px red solid;
}
ul.vertical-nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="header">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">DOWNLOAD</a></li>
        <li><a href="">POPULAR</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONNECT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="vertical-nav">
        <li><a href="">HOME</a><img src="icon.png"></li>
        <li><a href="">DOWNLOAD</a><img src="icon.png"></li>
        <li><a href="">POPULAR</a><img src="icon.png"></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a><img src="icon.png"></li>
        <li><a href="">CONNECT</a><img src="icon.png"></li>
    </ul>
    <img style="float:left;" src="image.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Ans 2) You can add float:left for image tag/image container to make it beside vertical menu. (Please note that vertical menu should also have float:left property.)